# calling saveContext on NSManagedObjectContext too much

Tags: ios, core-data

I was wondering if you can call NSManagedObjectContext save too often.  My save code is the standard UIApplicationDelegate code:

```
- (void)saveContext
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (managedObjectContext != nil) {
        if ([managedObjectContext hasChanges] && ![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            abort();
        }
    }
}
```

I have an app that brings up a modal to create a new Alarm type object.  The modal has a couple screens to it, like repeating days.  Similar to Apple's repeating days view, I push a new viewController that shows just the repeating days.  When I go back to the main screen of the modal where the user enters the name of the alarm, can I just call saveContext?  I guess I was wondering if I ever need to worry about calling saveContext for the smaller screens, like repeating days, and then the user hits Done on the main modal screen and I immediately call saveContext again.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only got one `NSManagedObjectContext` across the whole application you don't need to call `-save` on the context too often (as long as your app doesn't crash!). In cases like this I usually save when leaving an edit screen if some information has been changed and also save in the app delegates `-applicationDidEnterBackground:`.

If you've got a lot of changes (new objects, updated, etc) then calling save on that be a bit expensive as it has to write those changes to the persisted store (the file on the disk - assuming you're using `NSPersistedStore` which you usually are).